# Laravel - Two domains, same server, different page

Tags: php, laravel, url, dns, routes

I have got a Laravel website a: www.website.com and b: www.website.co.kr.
As you can see website b has a different extension 'co.kr'.

Both urls route to the same server. Most pages are the same for both websites, but some pages are different.

I want to handle this in my routing.

So for example:

www.website.com/about-us

www.website.co.kr/about-us

Shows a different page.

Right now I handle this using a group:

```
$co_kr_routes = function () {
    Route::get('/about-us', [
        'uses' => 'Frontend\Korea\PagesController@getAboutUs',
    ]);
};

Route::group(['domain' => 'www.website.co.kr'], $co_kr_routes);

//Default
Route::get('/about-us', [
    'uses' => 'Frontend\PagesController@getAboutUs',
]);
```

This works, but I am not satisfied with the solution and it is causing me not being able to cache the routes 'php artisan route:cache' because of the duplicate route '/about-us'.

My question is:

- Is there a nicer way to handle different extensions but same server resulting in showing a different page?

I didn't find much help googling the issue.
Right now I have to very specifically give the .co.kr domain to the group but it would be nicer if I could filter on 'co.kr' instead of the full domain.

I thought a solution would be handling this in the controller method itself, but handling this using routes sounds like the way to go. I dont think the controller should know or care if a request was made from a .com or .co.kr extension.

Comment: can you not just check for the domain on your controller level and then differentiate which view to display / output to give? Is the only difference the language?

Comment: The co.kr has a different menu. Different rules apply in Korea for our service, so it needs some additional pages that are not necessary for the .com domain.
It would definitely be possible to handle this in the controller. But it would be nicer to have a different controller per url extension.

Comment: I think handling this in the routes is much cleaner than in the controller.

Comment: I think the only two ways to differentiate the routes are 1. the way you do it, 2. by using "if" and `request()->getHost()` for example. But I have another thought for you: "it would be nicer if I could filter on 'co.kr'". Have you tried `Route::group(['domain' => '{domain}.co.kr'], $co_kr_routes);` ?

Comment: `Route::group(['domain' => '{domain}.co.kr'], $co_kr_routes);`
would be perfect. But it was my first try and it gave some problems, because whatever is between {} would act as the first parameter where you would expect the 'page'. `{domain}.co.kr/{page}`
Thanks for thinking with me. I think that in the end I will have to use a check in the Controller.

So in the controller method, the page would be the second parameter.

Comment: Then create a dummy first parameter? You don't have to use it in your controller as long as you reference it. Laravel just needs to know that that is a placeholder.

Comment: That is scalable right now, for one controller. But not if it is going to be more controllers.